# Is there any differences between these jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the difference between the three samples below and which one is better (if any)?

```
$("#x span").hide();

$("#x").find("span").hide();

$("span", "#x").hide();
```

Comment: I don't see no difference. Why this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will all match the same thing; the *best* one is based on context. I would use the first example unless I had a variable pointing to an existing set. Then I would obviously use the `find()` method on it.

The old `$(selector, context)` (your third example) isn't seen much these days, probably because it translates to `$(context).find(selector)` behind the scenes anyway (and its easier to read that way).

Comment: in a blog post at nettuts i saw two term: "context" and "scope". Are they same here? if yes then i would appreciate an example where they differ. . .thanks :-)

Comment: @Seoul I'm not sure 100% what you mean. I used *context* in the meaning of the English term and have not used *scope* in my answer.

Comment: go to this link- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-jquery-beginners-can-test-and-improve-their-code/  and read comment by james padolsey (cmnt time:
April 30, 2010 at 2:01 am ) and reply of siddarth in the same thread regarding #3 of the post.

Answer (score -1):

These all make the same selection, however the first performs more poorly than the last two which perform about the same, see:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-perf-right-to-left/48

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-context-vs-find

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance/11

Comment: The performance result in IE, firefox, opera, chrome and safari is not same. for example is IE $(context selector) is faster than $(context).find(selector)